# Полнотекстовый поиск с выборкою с нескольких таблиц mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть 3 таблицы  post, files, tracker
Делаю полнотекстовый поиск по post,теперь мне нужно узнать информацию о файле, LEFT JOIN files ,рабочий пример:

```
$sql = $db->query( "SELECT *, MATCH title AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)as relev FROM post LEFT JOIN files ON files.news_id = post.id WHERE MATCH title AGAINST ('$search') >0 ORDER BY relev DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Потом перебираю циклом и добавляю информацию еще одним запросом к таблице tracker (их 10 в суме):

```
$m_tr = $db->super_query("SELECT link AS m_link, SUM(leechers) AS m_leechers, SUM(seeders) AS m_seeders, SUM(completed) AS m_completed FROM tracker WHERE fid='{$value['files_id']}' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Затрачивается много времени, помогите составить один правильный запрос???
[image: post], [image: files], [image: tracker]

Comment: а еще один джойн или подзапрос вместо цикла никак?

Comment: Уберите PHP-обвязку, оставьте только SQL-код. Замените фотографии на DDL и скрипты тестового наполнения (ещё лучше - сделайте тестовый fiddle), покажите требуемый результат на именно этом наполнении.

Comment: @teran , можно пример?